# How to loop around and display keys from a section in LabVIEW

Tags: file, dll, configuration-files, ini, labview

does anyone have an idea on how i can loop around and display each key from a section at once in LabVIEW?

In terms of configuration files (.ini)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your keys in section have the same data type, then it is quite easy:
[image]

In case if you do not know data type of the key value (for example, there is stored some cluster with different data types), then you could install **OpenG Variant Configuration File Library** via VI Package Manager, and it allows to read either the whole cluster, or keys one-by-one as variant:

[image]